# Does $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{P_n\ln(P_n)}$ converge to the golden ratio?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, golden-ratio

The sum $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln(n)}$ does not converge.

But the sum $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{P_n\ln(P_n)}$ where $P_n$ denotes the $n$th prime number appears to be.

Is that correct, and if so, how can we calculate the value of convergence?

Is it possible that this sum converges to the golden ratio ($\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$)?

Comment: That series does in fact converge since $p_n\sim n\log n +o(n\log n)$ (i.e. the Prime Number Theorem). Why would you think it converges to $\phi$?

Comment: @AdamHughes: Just based on empiric testing of course.

Comment: If this is true I would be **intensely** surprised.

Comment: @AdamHughes: If this is true **and** not yet published somewhere, then I would be intensely surprised.

Comment: Just curious, to what prime number did you compute this sum to?

Comment: @SandeepSilwal: Well... You got me... the largest one smaller than $100,000$, and the sum was around $1.55$. So I kinda figured it would be nice if the sum converged to the golden ratio at the infinity...

Comment: I'd be shocked if this converged to anything that has a name, let alone a quadratic irrational like $\phi$.

Comment: Terence Tao is over on MO. Poke him for a blog update ;). (I am only kidding of course) nice if it did work out to that limit.

Comment: @Chinny84: Who's that? Should I post this question on MO instead?

Comment: @barakmanos: Maybe the only person who could answer your question ;)

Comment: @SandeepSilwal: Well this person is not there by that username :)

Comment: @barakmanos he also goes by [Terry Tao](http://mathoverflow.net/users/766/terry-tao) and do a quick search on this polymath.

Comment: With the largest prime being 19999999 the sum is 1.57713...

Comment: You must have an error, I just computed the sum, its value is Pi/2. Terence Tao would approve.

Comment: @user1708: Proof please?

Comment: @SandeepSilwal I think it's supposed to be a joke.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With $P_n \approx n \ln(n)$, we should have $$\sum_{N}^\infty \dfrac{1}{P_n \ln(P_n)} \approx \int_N^\infty \dfrac{dx}{x \ln(x)^2} = \dfrac{1}{\ln N}$$
If the sum for $n$ up to $\pi(19999999) = 1270607$ is  $1.57713$, we'd expect
the remainder to be about $.071$, which would push the total to about $1.648$, too high for $\phi$.

Comment: Can you please explain the (capital) $N$ in your formula? My sum starts at $1$, so if that's what you meant then $\frac{1}{\ln1}$ is quite undefined.

Comment: @barak manos, for large $N$ one can approximate 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{P_n \ln(P_n)} \approx \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \dfrac{1}{P_n \ln(P_n)} + \sum_{n=N}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n \ln(n) \cdot \ln\left( n \ln(n)\right)} \approx \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \dfrac{1}{P_n \ln(P_n)} + \dfrac{1}{\ln N},$$ which is $\pm$ appropriate estimation.

Comment: @Oleg567: So the sum diverges????? (since $N=\infty$).

Comment: @barakmanos, why diverges? To estimate series more accurate, we can choose $N$ bigger and bigger. Series is convergent definitely.

Comment: @barakmanos, 1st step: to take $N=10$ (for instance), 2nd step: to take $N=100$, and so on ... $\dfrac{1}{\ln N} \rightarrow 0$, when $N\rightarrow +\infty$.

Comment: @Oleg567: Ooops :) Thanks.

Comment: @Oleg567: But that still doesn't mean that the sum converges...

Comment: @barakmanos, behavior/distribution of prime numbers, as Robert shown, is $P_n\approx n\ln n$, and this behavior causes convergence of series. We just split this series to $2$ convenient (for calculations) parts. Convergence of series is convergence of its "tail".

Answer (score 6):

1.63661632335... 
See http://oeis.org/A137245 and links therein
(also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function, scroll down to integral section)