# Numerical value of $\sum_{p \in \mathcal P} \frac1{p\ln p}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1029640/153012) we determine that the series $\sum_{p \in \mathcal P} \frac1{p\ln p}$ converges, where the sum runs over primes.

As I see the convergence is really slow. The partial sums for given $N$ finite upper limits are

$\begin{align}
N \quad & \text{partial sum}\\
100 \quad &  0.757042464018193\\
1000 \quad & 0.803993788114564\\
10000 \quad & 0.828779261095689\\
100000 \quad & 0.844238045700797\\
1000000 \quad & 0.854866046633956\\
\end{align}$

Upto the $1000000$th partial sum there is no significant digit. Could anyone give me the sum of this series for some significant digits? As many as you can, but at least $10$ digits would be nice.

**Edit.** My calculations above have an $1/(2 \ln 2)$ difference, because the sum runs from $p_2$.

Comment: I get partial sum $1.421567...$ for $N=97$

Comment: For the first 10,000 primes, I get $1.5501267...$

Comment: You are abolutelty write, in my calculations the sum runs from $p_2$.

Comment: You sum looks wrong, the sum to $1000000^{th}$ prime is around $1.57621356707841$.

In July 1998, Henri Cohen has computed the limit with up to 50 digits accuracy.
$$\sum_{p \in \mathcal{P}} \frac{1}{p\log p} \sim 1.63661632335126086856965800392186367118159707613129\ldots$$

Comment: @achillehui Yes, sorry. My calculation has an $1/2$ difference, because the sum runs from $p_2$. Could you give me a reference to the result what you've said?

Comment: Your difference should be $1/(2 \log 2)$, not $1/2$.

Comment: All the source I have refer to a paper "High precision computation of Hardy-Littlewood constants" by Henri Cohen. On Cohen's homepage, there is a [draft](http://www.math.u-bordeaux1.fr/~cohen/hardylw.dvi) for the preprint. But it is in dvi format which I cannot view. If you can view dvi file, give that a try.

Comment: $$998200001 \ \ \ \   1.588357254141502075976500372$$

Comment: So, even the primes upto $998200001$ lead to a very inaccurate result.

Comment: ? s=0;p=1;while(p<10^9,p=nextprime(p+1);s=s+1/p/log(p);if(Mod(p,10^5)==1,print(p
,"   ",s)))

Comment: I used the above command in PARI/GP to get the result.

Comment: The final result is :? print(p,"   ",s)
$1000000007 \ \ \ \   1.588361447267763827936188124$

Comment: So, the convergence is very slow indeed, which is no wonder because $$\sum_p \frac{1}{p}$$ is still divergent.

Comment: From the Henri Cohen paper: "Thus, it would be inconceivable to compute it using the naive method since even with a table of primes up to $10^{20}$ (already an impossible practical limit), we would obtain less than 2 decimal digits."

Comment: Wow, very very slow ...

Comment: Sorry about the mistakes, and thanks for the helpful comments. Yes, really slow.

Comment: I have previously asked a similar question at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/888571/131263. The answer there might be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sums seem wrong; they are all off by an additive factor of 1/(2 log 2).  Why you omitted the prime 2 is unknown to me.  Also by N you seem to mean "compute the sum up to and including the N'th prime".

In any event, you can find the value of this sum to about 45 digits here:

https://oeis.org/A137245